# Does RegEx a* match all strings?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following code:

```
string rex = "a*";
string txt = "cvb";
Regex regex = new Regex(rex);
Console.WriteLine("Success:" + regex.IsMatch(txt));
```

This code is returning **true** always.
I thought that a pattern a* will ONLY match: "" , "a", "aa", "aaa....".

I tested this situation [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/).

And the same example did not match.

Comment: At the test site you linked to, it does show that find() would work for that combination.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would only be the case for `^a*$`. Since you're not using the beginning and end anchors, it will always match "nothing" in any string.

Comment: the `^` and `$` anchors are important, but more important to the question is the difference between `*` and `+`, which you seem to have missed entirely.

Comment: Except he wants it to match "", so `+` is inappropriate.

Comment: @Spudley, I think *you* missed something, the OP *wants* to also match an empty string. He just didn't know `IsMatch` is returns partial matches.

Comment: hmm, yep; you may be right.  :)  (easy thing to miss, I guess; I think I was expecting the `a+` solution because it would be a more common requirement)

Answer (score 6):

If you take a closer look at the RegexPlanet results you'll see that, while the `matches()` method fails, both `find()` and `lookingAt()` return `true`.  `matches()` implicitly anchors the match at both ends, as if you had written `^a*$`.  `lookingAt()` auto-anchors the match at the beginning only, and find() doesn't anchor it at all.

Of course, those are all Java methods, that being the regex flavor used by RegexPlanet.  .NET's `IsMatch()` method is equivalent to Java's `find()`, and it has no equivalent for `matches()` or `lookingAt()` (and doesn't need them).  If you want the match anchored, you have to anchor it yourself.

Comment: Ah. Yes. This gets "+1: Insightful". That explains very well how the OP's confusion arose in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

A star in a regex indicates zero or more occurrances of the preceding item".

In this case, the prededing item is the "a" character, and there is nothing else in the regex.

Therefore, this regex says "zero or more 'a' characters".

Since you state that you're expecting to match 'a', 'aa' or 'aaa' with your `a*`, then what you probably want instead of the star is a plus sign. This would indicate "one or more of the preceding item".

[EDIT]

As @Bindy says, if you want to match an empty string as well as any number of 'a's (a point which I missed), then you will need to also match for that.

In this case, @Bindy's solution would work.

Alternatively, a solution using the `a+` would look like this:

```
(a+|^$)
```

this would match either one or more 'a's, or an empty string. Note that this is different to @Bindy's soltion in that his solution only matches where the string only contains 'a's and nothing else, whereas mine will match any string containing one or more 'a's, or an empty string.

Your examples didn't really cover which of those would be what you want (my hunch is you indended something closer to @Bindy's answer than this, but I felt I should still add it here)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I do not understand is why differents regexp implementations throws different results.

Comment: @gonzalog, different how? Something this simple will be consistent across pretty much all modern regex implementations.

Comment: @gonzalog - I think @Alan Moore's answer explains the answer to that question quite well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use next

```
^a*$
```

Seems to [work](http://www.rubular.com/r/F7rM4B9FPL)

Answer (score -1):

a* is telling the Regex interpreter to match a 0 to many times. I believe what you want is `a.*`, or if you want it to effect the entire string, and only match if the first character is a, then `$a.*^`

Comment: I take it it's actually: `^a$`. And in any case the `+` sign ressembles more the `*` than the `.`.